# How to get the maximum distance between a polygons centroid and its outer ring?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, computational-geometry

I got the centroid `x_0, y_0` of a polygon and two lists of points `list_x, list_y`which represent the row and column indexes of vertices for my polygon, respectively. They were obtained from a 2D semantic mask using shapely.
How can i find the maximum distance between my polygon and the polygon centroid using python?

Comment: Seems like you're asking more than "find furthest point in a set of points from another point". Are you?

Comment: @weston actually i want to find the biggest distance

Comment: OK then: Seems like you're asking more than "find furthest distance from one point to a set of points". Are you?

Comment: It suffices to remark that the maximum distance is to some vertex, and compare the distances to the vertices. (This does not work with the *minimum* distance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do :

```
max_dist = 0
for i in range(len(list_x)):
    dist = (abs(list_x[i]-x_0)**2 + abs(list_y[i]-y_0)**2)**0.5
    if dist > max_dist:
        max_dist = dist

# max_dist should know be the maximum distance to centroid
```